# Android: Open pdf file with the specified software

Tags: android

Now I have downloaded a .pdf file from website and wanna open it with the **specified software** like "**Adobe Reader**".How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe your question should clarify that you'd like to open the file with the software _you_ specify... because with intents and using LuxuryMode's code, you can open the file with the software _specified by the user_...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by adding the method "`Intent.setComponent(pkg,cls);`".
**PS:** I don Not angry about downing my reps.And thank you for giving me the suggestions.
**PSS:** What I wanna say is "Not everyone will get the same apple." I post this question for I have this problem and it occured in Android App.And Someone told me "Cannot".I post my answer just to tell you Ive solved this(or just mine) problem,and maybe it will help someone who has the problem same as mine.Yeah,this answer may make no sense to you.
**PSSS:**:-)But I still think the API make sense to me and to its Designer.
**PSSSS:**At last,thank you all.And forgive my poor English.

Comment: But even if you can specify the package, you can't be sure adobe reader is availble on the device. I really dont see why you should care which PDF reader is used. Just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @LuxuryMode: agreed, this goes against allowing your users to choose which apps they prefer, and will fail miserably for users who don't have the software you're trying to force them to use. And just "add the method such-and-such" as an answer will not help anyone trying to understand what to do. -1 from me, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You cant. All you can do is fire off an intent and let the system handle it. If the user already has a default app that they've chosen to handle PDFs, that's the one that will open the PDF.

In general it's something like:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/example.pdf");

                if (file.exists()) {
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    try {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } .......
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Yeah,I've done this.But I really wanna open it with specified software.

Comment: @ZhaoRocky, Actually, you can. Just use an explicit intent. You should be able to find one for a pdf reader. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ires

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I have read thi page,But I still confused about how to make an explicit intent.Can you give me an example or snippet?Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ZhaoRocky, Actually, the snippet you posted up there looks good. Just note that in Android, there isn't only one package name, there are usually two package names. We only think there is one package name, because the 'New android project...' Wizard assigns the same name for both packages. So when you set your component, you have to assign the package name of the application in your first argument, and you have to specify the second.package.name in front of your dot class name in your second argument. Also, don't forget, you need to pass in the reference to the pdf file.

Comment: This response seems to answer the vague question as I interpreted it when I first read it, +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You should first have a look at the [intents filters documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html). Then you can start an intent (after adding the intent filter) for your PDF file.